# How can I fix “this command is not available” error message?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I’m taking the “Word Automation with StudioX” course on UiPath.
I downloaded the solution of the practice exercise but when I run it I see this screen
[image]
How can I fix this error?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate packages installed?